# monitor log of a pod with dynamic name

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I need to automate monitoring log of pods of an app

Monitoring a pod's log can be done using oc CLI

`oc log -f my-app-5-43j`

However, the pod's name changes dynamically over the deployments. If I want to automate the monitoring, like running a cron job, continually tailing the log even after another deployment, how should I do?

Comment: I _think_ you can specify a `dc` or use a label. Check `oc log -h`

Answer (score 2):

Will Gordon already commented solution, so I provide more practical usage for your understanding.

If you deploy your pod using `deploymentConfig`, `daemonSet` and so on, you can see logs of the pod without specifying a `pod name` as follows.

```
# oc logs -f dc/<your deploymentConfig name>
# oc logs -f ds/<your daemonset name>
```

Or you can get first pod name dynamically using `jsonpath` output option to see log.

```
# oc logs -f $(oc get pod -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')
```

If you can specify the pod with a specific label, you can use `-l` option either.

```
# oc logs -f $(oc get pod -l app=database -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')
```